# Issue with Microsoft’s Edge version’s compatibility with MSEdgeDriver version(84,85,86)

Tags: microsoft-edge, selenium-edgedriver

I downloaded the latest version:83.0.478.61 (Official build) (64-bit) of Edge from https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/edge, but I am not able to make it work with selenium. It appears that selenium’s Edger drivers in (https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/tools/webdriver/) only work for Edge versions 86, 85, and 84! If the latest version of MS Edge browser is 83 why there are versions of Selenium Edge driver for Edge versions 84, 85, or 86? I tried all 3 drivers with my latest edge browser and got similar errors. Is there a way to bypass this or download Edge browser versions 84, 85, or 86?

1. **Message: OneTimeSetUp: System.InvalidOperationException : session not created: This version of MSEdgeDriver only supports MSEdge version 84 (SessionNotCreated)**
2. **Message: OneTimeSetUp: System.InvalidOperationException : session not created: This version of
   MSEdgeDriver only supports MSEdge version 85 (SessionNotCreated)**
3. **Message: OneTimeSetUp: System.InvalidOperationException : session not created: This version of MSEdgeDriver only supports MSEdge version 86 (SessionNotCreated)**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a way to bypass this or download Edge browser versions 84, 85, or 86?

If you are using .NET and downloading the driver via the Nuget package `Selenium.WebDriver.MSEdgeDriver`, just download the correct version (not necessary the latest version)

[image: Choose the correct version]

Answer (score 0):

> why there are versions of Selenium Edge driver for Edge versions 84, 85, or 86?

Because the latest version:83.0.478.61 (Official build) (64-bit) of Edge is just the latest **stable** version. There're other versions of Edge Chromium which have higher version number, such as Edge Canary version 86.0.572.0:

[image]

> Is there a way to bypass this or download Edge browser versions 84, 85, or 86?

If you still want to use Edge stable version 83.0.478.61, you could download the 83.0.478.61 Edge WebDriver in [this link](https://msedgewebdriverstorage.z22.web.core.windows.net/):

[image]

If you want to download Edge browser versions higher than the stable version, you could check [this link](https://www.microsoftedgeinsider.com/en-us/download).

Comment: Hi, is the driver forward compatible? If i download the edgedriver version for say 83, will it work with all future releases of Edge? I want to make a utility which uses selenium automation but i don't want it to break it later when browser version gets updated

Comment: I think it's not forward compatible. You need to use the same version with the browser's version.

Comment: Okey, is there some capability settings that i  can use for launching edge in IE compatible mode? I had started a separate question on this but didn&#39;t get any response

Comment: I'll check it later.